# Getting grey screen when open camera with Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, android-camera, barcode-scanner, android-camera-intent

I want to use the camera in my Flutter app to scan Barcodes. But everytime I try to open the camera on an Android device I get a grey screen which only disappear when I stop the app and restart it.

I use the package `flutter_barcode_scanner` to open camera and scan barcode.
This is the error I get in the console:

`Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)`

Here is my code but I dont think that the problem is the code itself:

```
  Future scanBarcode() async {
    String scanResult = '';
    try {
      scanResult = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
          'ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.BARCODE);
    } on PlatformException {
      print('ERROR');
    }
    if (!mounted) return;
    print(scanResult);
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem. It usually happens when we did not pass the right parameters in FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode() method. In ur case, you forgot to put '#' in your hex color string. So replace "ff6666" with "#ff6666" and It should work.